# How make FILE* from HANDLE in WinApi?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Is there easy way to create FILE* from WinApi HANDLE which points to one end of pipe?
Something like we do in unix: `fdopen(fd,<mode>);`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do this but you have to do it in two steps. First, call [`_open_osfhandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-osfhandle) to get a C run-time file descriptor from a Win32 HANDLE value, then call [`_fdopen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fdopen-wfdopen) to get a `FILE*` object from the file descriptor.

Comment: Does those function take ownership of the underlying handle, or should CloseHandle still be called?

Comment: @user877329: I think you still need to call `CloseHandle()`, but it would be worth checking. It's been quite some time since I have used those functions. The Microsoft runtime library source code comes with the compiler so you can write a test program and trace it to check.

Answer (score 4):

```
FILE* getReadBinaryFile(LPCWSTR path) {
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { 
        return nullptr; 
    }
    int nHandle = _open_osfhandle((long)hFile, _O_RDONLY);
    if (nHandle == -1) { 
        ::CloseHandle(hFile);   //case 1
        return nullptr; 
    }
    FILE* fp = _fdopen(nHandle, "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        ::CloseHandle(hFile);  //case 2
    }
    return fp;
}
```

my code for get an open read binary file descriptor.

you should use fclose to close FILE* if you don't need it .

i didn't test for case 1 and 2, so use it at your own risk.

Comment: Case 2 must be _close(nHandle) instead, closes also the underlying hFile.

Answer (score -1):

you can't exchange(convert) them.. if you need to have a file with FILE* and HANDLE you need to open it twice