# how to get the name of a file in C++ using Win32 Handle?

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I'm trying to get the name of a file using Win32 handle in C++.

I have two more concerns, the file might be empty (opening the file may not work) and I can't use all the fancy functions (e.g. GetFinalPathNameByHandle) which are supported by Windows Vista and above.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean "Handler"? POSIX file descriptor? C stdio FILE? C++ iostreams fstream? Win32 API something? Qt something else?

Comment: I think he means a Win32 `HANDLE` receieved from `CreateFile`?

Comment: He should say that! And tag the question with `winapi`. It's not a C++ question, it's a Windows programming question.

Comment: I edited the question in order to clarify it. Unfortunately, I am still unable to provide an answer to it with the amount of informations you gave us. Could you also clarify what do you mean by "use all the fancy functions"? Do you mean that you cannot use STL?

Comment: hey, fancy ways means i can't use GetFinalPathNameByHandle for example, handler means win32 handler, (C++ HANDLE type).
as far as i understood using files mapping wont work since the file may be empty of content.

Comment: A `HANDLE` is a reference to something, a _handler_ is a processor, very different.

Comment: Peter Wood: thanks for the *fix, i meant HANDLE

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5193579/1084416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For XP+ you can map the file then call `GetMappedFileName` which will return the name (although not for directories). See [Obtaining a File Name From a File Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know win32, but I do know about sysinternals process explorer. Google came up with an open source alternative: http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/

Maybe studying that code will enable you do this.

Answer (score 0):

`GetMappedFilename()` is not the best solution although recommended in the MSDN.

I have posted the code that does exactly what you want ready for copy and paste here:
[How to get name associated with open HANDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65170/how-to-get-name-associated-with-open-handle/18792477#18792477)