# PInvoking stdin, stdout and stderr to unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a C header file that contains something like this:

```
void init(FILE* in, FILE* out, FILE* err);
```

I'm guessing this equates to the following PInvoke signature:

```
[DllImportAttribute("mylib", EntryPoint = "init")]
public static extern void init(IntPtr @in, IntPtr @out, IntPtr err);
```

Incidentally, I want to invoke this method. Can I get the IntPtr from Console.In, Console.Out, Console.Error somehow?

It should work on Linux and Windows, and not Windows exclusively.

Comment: Not duplicate. Needs to work on Linux as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetStdHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) to obtain handles to the standart input(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), output(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) and error(STD_ERROR_HANDLE) file.

You can then write and read from those files using WriteFile, ReadFile functions.

After that, if you still need a FILE structure, follow these steps to create one.

[How make FILE* from HANDLE in WinApi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5193795/2016727)

Comment: Should have mentioned it, but I'm working on Linux. Nevertheless, I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: Thanks for your response :),
So  actually in linux, you can use fdopen to obtain a FILE structure for a file descriptor. `FILE *f = fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "w");`